# PHP the_date with setlocale not working

Tags: php, wordpress, date, setlocale

I have in wordpress the echo the_date function to display the posts date. I want to modify it to Hungarian. I tried with setlocale but its not working (maybe date is not editable with setlocale?)
Can anyone please help me with it?

Currently it looks like this

```html
<span class="single-date"><?php setlocale(LC_TIME,'hu_HU.utf-8'); echo the_date('F d, Y');  ?> </span>
```

Date shows up like this: February 03, 2015

I need to modify the month name to hungarian.

Thank you!

Comment: date() is not locale-aware. whatever the_date() is using would have be modded to use `strftime()` instead.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the reply. How can i convert the output of the_date() to strftime() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out your WordPress settings instead. You can set your timezone there, and also edit what the_date displays in forms of the date format.

Comment: Timezone is set to the correct one, i think the wordpress language needs to be set to hungarian, but i can't do that (it needs to be english). Only the month name needs to be hungarian. Date format is also set correcly.